# No Routes Matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There is an association with course and course instance. When I visit the url /courses/1/course_instances/new, I get the error below.

This is the error I got:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"course_instances", :course_id=>nil}
```

Models

Course:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :code, :credits, :description, :hours, :id, :name, :pass_mark
   has_many :course_instances, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_instances
end
```

Course Instance

```
class CourseInstance < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :end_date, :id, :start_date
   belongs_to :course
end
```

Routes

```
Sis::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :courses do
     resources :course_instances
   end
   root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Course Instance Controller

```
class CourseInstancesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_course

  def new
    @course_instance = @course.course_instances.build
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
    end
  end

  def find_course
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for ([@course, @course_instance]) do |f| %>
   ---- excluded for brevity ----
```

Rake Routes

```
new_course_course_instance GET    /courses/:course_id/course_instances/new(.:format)     course_instances#new
```

Comment: what is the result of "$rake routes" ?

Comment: For what URL do you get the error?

Comment: /courses/1/course_instances/new

Comment: I edited my question to include the rakes routes output

Comment: Do you have a course instance with id = 1 ?

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code. Maybe restarting the server helps?

Comment: Nope, I trying to create a course instance for a course.

Comment: did that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: there is course with the id =1 but in the error it has a value of nil.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what I did but it started to work. I tried backtracking to recreate the error  however I have been unsuccessful so far. Weird! Thanks for the help from everyone!